# How to install "googlemaps" module in Python?

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, pip

How can I install the googlemaps module from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlemaps/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why that particular version? Does `pip install googlemaps`, which is version 2.4.3 currently, not satisfy your needs?